# Oracle database table row count

Tags: database, oracle11g

I want to take a table row count of a particular table  precisely in my application. Rather than running a SQL count query,  Is there way to fetch a table row count from oracle database engine?

Comment: I'm afraid what you need is nonsense. Oracle does know it, it is not necessary maintain such an information. Even if there was a way, such a value is usually useless, when running in multi-user concurrent environment. Before the value is sent to you, it can be different in reality. `ALL_TABLES` view contains a value from the last statistics gathering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way by which you can achieve rows it directly from Oracle database engine.

However if you dont want to use COUNT query then there are other ways by which you can get the result faster in case your table is huge like

```
SELECT NUM_ROWS FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = your_table_name;
```

Comment: I tried the query you provided, but it gives me Null. But my table is not empty

Comment: @user1516815:- Can you show the query which you have tried?

Comment: SELECT NUM_ROWS FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STUDENTLOG';

Comment: @user1516815:- And what does select count(*) from STUDENTLOG returns?

Comment: select count(*) from STUDENTLOG  returns 20.

Comment: @user1516815:- Also note that ALL_TABLES view contains a value from the last statistics gathering.

Comment: How to run statistics gathering manually? I think that's the issue in my case.

Comment: @user1516815:- So what is the harm in using count(*) since your table is too small you can use count(*). Also to mention again Oracle does not provide any such facility to get that directly

Comment: @user1516815:- If you want you can use the `exec DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS;` This will update the statistics. You can refer this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm#i1036194

Comment: No, My table is not that much small. row count is growing rapidly.

Comment: @user1516815:- I gave you the command to update statistics. Hope that helps!